# Unknown Segmentation Fault Error in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I compile my code everything compiles successfully, but when I run my code I receive a "segmentation fault error". What is causing this error? As far as I can tell I've dotted all my i's and crossed all my t's.

-I edited my code to reflect some of the suggested changes but still get the same error-
My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[100];
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int *even_elt_sum_ptr = 0;
    int *odd_elt_sum_ptr = 0;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter elements in array: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }//end of for loop

    sum(a, n, even_elt_sum_ptr, odd_elt_sum_ptr);

}//end of main

int sum(int a[], int n, int *even_elt_sum_ptr, int *odd_elt_sum_ptr)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            *even_elt_sum_ptr += a[i];
        }//end of if statement
        else
        {
            *odd_elt_sum_ptr += a[i];
        }//end of else statement

    }//end of for loop
    printf("%d\n", *even_elt_sum_ptr);
    printf("%d\n", *odd_elt_sum_ptr);

}//end of sum function
```

Comment: This statement   values[10] = values[n]; does not make sense. Arrays do not have the assignment operator. Moreover the array is not used in the program.

Comment: Use a debugger, and step through your code line-by-line

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Surely it does? It assigns the value of values[n] to values[10]? (On a side note values[10] is out of bound though) Or am I just being tired

Comment: @jpw I am sure he means an assignment of arrays.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yeah, reading the code more carefully it would seem he wanted to size the array at runtime which would have needed a malloc or something similar. (ie dynamic memory alloc)

Comment: You really need to review how arrays and pointers work in C. This code has numerous errors regarding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you have to declare the function `sum` before its usage in `main`.

The function `sum` is declared as having the return type `int` but returns nothing.

The array

```
int values[10];
```

is not used in the program. And moreover this statement

```
values[10] = values[n];
```

does not make sense. It seems you are trying to redefine the array in this statement however arrays do not have the assignment operator and may not be redefined.

These declarations

```
int *even_elt_sum_ptr = 0;
int *odd_elt_sum_ptr = 0;
```

also do not make sense. You should declare at least objects of the type `int`

```
int even_elt_sum = 0;
int odd_elt_sum = 0;
```

and pass them to the function `sum` by reference as for example

```
sum(a, n, &even_elt_sum, &odd_elt_sum);
```

It seems what you mean is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   100

void sum( const int a[], size_t n, long long int *even_elt_sum_ptr, long long int *odd_elt_sum_ptr);

int main(void)
{
    int a[N];
    long long int even_elt_sum;
    long long int odd_elt_sum;

    size_t n = N;

    printf( "Enter size of array (no more than %zu): ", ( size_t )N );
    scanf( "%zu", &n);

    if ( n == 0 || N < n ) n = N;

    printf( "Enter %zu elements in array: ", n );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }//end of for loop

    sum( a, n, &even_elt_sum, &odd_elt_sum );

    printf( "%lld\n", even_elt_sum );
    printf( "%lld\n", odd_elt_sum );
}//end of main method for problem 4

void sum( const int a[], size_t n, long long int *even_elt_sum_ptr, long long int *odd_elt_sum_ptr )
{
    *even_elt_sum_ptr = 0;
    *odd_elt_sum_ptr = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] % 2 == 0 )
        {
            *even_elt_sum_ptr += a[i];
        }//end of if statement
        else
        {
            *odd_elt_sum_ptr += a[i];
        }//end of else statement
    }//end of for loop
}//end of sum function
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter size of array (no more than 100 ): 10
Enter 10 elements in array: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
20
25
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared the `sum`-function to take an array of integers, named `a`.

However, when you call the function, you are only passing a single integer, and an invalid one at that!

```
int a[100];         // Declare an array: valid indicies are [0] to [99]
sum(a[100], .... ); // Try to pass the single integer, a[100], which is not valid!

int sum(int a[], ... ) // The function expects an ARRAY, not a single, undefined value.
```

Comment: You fail to address the issues with the bad initialization of the even and odd pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line:

```
sum(a[100], n, *even_elt_sum_ptr, *odd_elt_sum_ptr);
```

you should write this line:

```
sum(a, n, even_elt_sum_ptr, odd_elt_sum_ptr);
```

`a` is already an array (you wrote `int a[100]`). By writing `a[100]` as an argument, you mean "Consider a as an array, take the 101th element an give it as the argument", so you give an `int` not an `int`array).

Also, the 3rd and 4th arguments are already pointers (declared as `int *...`), by putting a star when passing them as arguments, you actually dereference them, i.e. take the `int` the pointers point to.

These error should be indicated by your compiler (actually, your compiler should indicate warnings, but in C, if you don't exactly know what you are doing, you should consider warnings the same as errors).

Comment: You fail to address the issues with the bad initialization of the even and odd pointers.